# Running Spring boot locally with a MySQL container as dependency?

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, spring-config

After some radical changes to our schema and reading some posts on why you should avoid in memory databases.

We have decided to use MySQL locally for testing and developing. Using a MySQL docker container with a volume for persistence.

This is fairly straightforward however the issues we are having are the following:

- Requires the container to be executed separate from the spring boot application (a manual task `docker run`
- Same goes for stopping the container, its a independant process

My question is essentially, is it possible to have spring boot (when using a dev config profile) to manage this docker container.

i.e. I start development work in IntelliJ and run the service, the service checks if the container is running, if not starts it up.

If this idea is bad, then please let me know.

For testing its not issue, because we are using a maven docker plugin to create the container during the maven lifecycle.

Its more for devs working locally, and getting the service running locally with ease.

Any suggestions welcomed!

Bonus for Intellij setup!